# Does Vis Timeline tooltips work timeline - groups-ordering?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm trying to get tooltips working with Timeline | Groups ordering.
I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: No container provided
>       at Timeline.Core._create (vis.js:9748)
>       at new Timeline (vis.js:40685)

Are there any examples of Timeline | Groups ordering with tooltips?

Looking at http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/items/tooltip.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Timeline | Groups ordering</title>

     <style>
        body, html {
          font-family: arial, sans-serif;
          font-size: 11pt;
        }

        #visualization {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          height: 300px;
        }

    </style>

      <script src="./dist/moment.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./dist/vis.js"></script>
      <link href="./dist/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> Oracle Database </h1>
    <div id="tooltips-follow">
        <div class="menu">
            <input type="image" src="dist/img/network/plus.png" id="zoomIn" value="Zoom in"/>
            <input type="image" src="dist/img/network/minus.png" id="zoomOut" value="Zoom out"/>
            <input type="image" src="dist/img/network/leftArrow.png" id="moveLeft" value="Move left"/>
            <input type="image" src="dist/img/network/rightArrow.png" id="moveRight" value="Move right"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>

      var groups = new vis.DataSet([
    {id:0, content: "Database Roadmap", value: 0},
    ...
    ]);

      // create a dataset with items
      // note that months are zero-based in the JavaScript Date object, so month 3 is April
      var items = new vis.DataSet([
     {id:1, group:0, content: "Full", className: "Full", start: new Date(2018, 01, 01), end: new Date(2022, 06, 30), title: 'Start Date2010, 07, 01<br> End Date2010, 07, 01'},
     ...
    ]);

      // create visualization
      var container = document.getElementById('tooltips-follow');
      var options = {
        // option groupOrder can be a property name or a sort function
        // the sort function must compare two groups and return a value
        //     > 0 when a > b
        //     < 0 when a < b
        //       0 when a == b
        groupOrder: function (a, b) {
          return a.value - b.value;
        },
        start: new Date(),
        end: new Date(1000*60*60*36864 + (new Date()).valueOf()),
        stack: false,
        editable: false,
        clickToUse: true
      };
      var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container);
      timeline.setOptions(options);
      timeline.setGroups(groups);
      timeline.setItems(items);
        function move (percentage) {
            var range = timeline.getWindow();
            var interval = range.end - range.start;

            timeline.setWindow({
                start: range.start.valueOf() - interval * percentage,
                end:   range.end.valueOf()   - interval * percentage
            });
        }
        // attach events to the navigation buttons
        document.getElementById('zoomIn').onclick    = function () { timeline.zoomIn( 0.2); };
        document.getElementById('zoomOut').onclick   = function () { timeline.zoomOut( 0.2); };
        document.getElementById('moveLeft').onclick  = function () { move( 0.2); };
        document.getElementById('moveRight').onclick = function () { move(-0.2); };

      // Follow options
      var follow_options = {
        tooltip: {
          followMouse: true
        }
      };

      var timelineFollow = new vis.Timeline(document.getElementById('tooltips-follow'),
          items, follow_options);


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It seems tooltips-follow does not support groups with options! I now get a timeline with groups and no tooltips and a separate timeline with no groups and tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

So it works by just adding the title tag and using the follow option does not work. Thanks

Comment: Would be nice of you if you show what exactly have you changed to fix your issue and also accept your answer so that one can see at once that the problem is sovled. Best regards